# Error: java.io.IOException: The handle is invalid

Tags: java, apache-commons-io

I am trying to move file from one location to another
When i run the .jar through command prompt it's working fine but when jar has been trigger from Robot scheduler(with different service account) getting below error

```
java.io.IOException: The handle is invalid
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1076)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1040)
```

The method which i am using for fileMove is below

```
public static Boolean fileMove(File source, String destination) {
    LOG.info(destination + File.separator + source.getName());
    LOG.info(source.getAbsolutePath());
    File dest = new File(destination + File.separator + source.getName());


     try {
         FileUtils.copyFile(source, dest);
         return FileUtils.contentEquals(source, dest) && Files.deleteIfExists(source.toPath());
     } catch (IOException e) {
         LOG.warn("IO Error Occurred during file Operations", e);
         return false;
     }
}
```

*`LOG.info(destination + File.separator + source.getName())`* is logging below path
      //uk001/eucl/Email_Broker_Archive\mime-message--7431406574003289236.eml
 ***(destination=//uk001/eucl/Email_Broker_Archive,
File.separator='\', source.getName()=mime-message--7431406574003289236.eml***

*`LOG.info(source.getAbsolutePath())`*  is logging below path

***\uk001\eucl\Source\0002\mime-message--7431406574003289236.eml***

R/W Permission is there for both service account(cmd and Robot scheduler) and the application is running on windows server.

Comment: Your code block is needed to check. Your exception trace is not sufficient either to point out which ones cause error. Update the questions with proper details for people to help you.

Comment: You should give more details. The code would be good; also the source and destination, if either isn't hard coded. One guess is that the working directory is different, and one or both of the paths is relative.

Comment: Hi @ Karthik R and @yshavit Thanks for the comment,have updated question

Comment: @UchitShah Did you end up modifying the file during the execution?

Comment: @nullpointer No

Comment: @UchitShah The paths that you logged seems indifferent and destination seems incorrect. What is the `File.separator` in your case, where is it imported from?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the comment @nullpointer in my case File.separator is forward slashe('\')

Comment: @UchitShah then why is your destination using backslashes "/" ? I believe the file system would follow either of these, not both simultaneously and that might be the cause of the exception as well.

Comment: @nullpointer i am using shared path,i believe path is mounted on unix server if i provide source as backslashes got the error: java.lang.illegalArgumentException: Mailformed \uxxxx encoding

Comment: ideally, could you try just replacing in your code File.separator with "/" and check if that fixes it? Also, the malformed exception probably occurs while decoding the path you provided.

Comment: @nullpointer Just saw your comments. Please post that as your answer as well and let him check.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue of File separator not matching the OS's file separator.

**//uk001/eucl/Email_Broker_Archive\mime-message--7431406574003289236.eml**

Please replace and check if the \ is the issue.
Also, do an if check if the file exists before copying the file all the time.

```
if (!Files.exists(dest)) {
    FileUtils.copyFile(source, dest);
    return FileUtils.contentEquals(source, dest) && Files.deleteIfExists(source.toPath());
//Modify the check above accordingly as the file exists check is already done.
 }
```

Comment: sorry for the late comment,problem got solved,issue with service account permission i was in wrong impression that R/W permission is there for service account,ones it given it solved.Thanks for all support